# Why grep doesn't show me the matching word until the next space?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a `temp` file, and I want to `grep` the only word that matches the pattern instead of whole word. i tried `grep -o <pattern> file` but its not giving me desired output

#### Input

```
xi29 vddf vss vddf vss int_s s2 rstb mg91a02_l_nd2_bulk_vt1 ln1=16n ln2=16n lp1=16n lp2=16n nf_n1=1 nf_n2=1 nf_p1=1 nf_p2=1  
xi28 vddf vss vddf vss d1 d mg91a02_l_inv_bulk_vt1 ln=16n lp=16n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=2 nfin_p=2 m=1  
xi25 vddf vss vddf vss int_m2 int_m1 mg91a02_l_inv_bulk_vt1 ln=16n lp=16n nf_n=1 nf_p=1
```

#### Command

```
grep -o 'mg91a02' temp
```

#### Output (obtained)

```
mg91a02
mg91a02
mg91a02
```

#### Output (desired)

```
mg91a02_l_nd2_bulk_vt1
mg91a02_l_inv_bulk_vt1
mg91a02_l_inv_bulk_vt1
```

Comment: @garethTheRed i want output as above .. but all i get is `mg9102` **version** grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
 grep -E -o 'mg91a02\w+'
```

where

- `-E` : extended regexp
- `-o`  print only matched word
- `\w` : *word* characters (alphanumerics or underscore, synonym for `[_[:alnum:]]`).
- `+` one or more time

For non-whitespace characters, so as to catch strings with `@` as per comment, see `\S` (short for `[^[:space:]]`)

```
grep -E -o 'mg91a02\S+'
```

with edited input from the OP, this results in

```
mg91a02_l_inv_bulk_vt1
mg91a02_l_nd2_bulk_vt1
mg91a02_l_nd2_@bulk!_vt1
mg91a02_l_nd2_[bulk]_vt1
mg91a02_l_inv_bulk_vt1
```

Note that `-o`, `\w` and `\S` are non-standard extensions.

Comment: Hmm. \w doesn't seem to match only non-whitespace. For example I just saw it stop matching on a '@'.

Comment: @Harv good catch, see my edit.

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -o 'mg91a02[^ ]*' file
```

This means print pattern `mg91a02` until not seen`^` first space(`[^ ]`) or means print everything which is not a space.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl regular expressions:

```
grep -Po '\w*mg91a02\w*'
```

For example:

```
$ grep -Po top .zshrc
top
top
top
top
top
top
top
$ grep -Po '\w*top\w*' .zshrc
setopt
setopt
autopushd
setopt
setopt
setopt
setopt
```